# Trying to use spirals to show an image in p5.js

Tags: p5.js

I have an image which I am trying to show using a spiral with varying thickness depending upon the image pixel. But the thickness of my line/ellipses in spiral is not coming out correctly.

[The image I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF7pv.png):
[image: blackcircle on a white background]

[The image I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psurc.png)
[image: A spiral of small black dots on a light green background where the black dots have a larger size in the bottom right quarter of the image (when it should have been from the top left corner)]

As you can see for whatever reason the bottom right quadrant is getting thick and nothing else, this is happening even if I use other images.

My code:

```
FG = '#222323';
BG = '#f0f6f0';

function preload() {    
    Img = loadImage('black.png');
}


function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    Img.resize(500, 500);
    background(BG);
    fill(FG);
    colorMode(HSB, 255);
    noLoop();
    noStroke(); 
}

function draw() {   
    var r = width;
    var a = 0;
    while (r > 1) {
        strokeWeight(1);
        var x1 = r * cos(a);
        var y1 = r * sin(a);
        
        a += 0.01;
        r -= 0.03;
        
        var x2 = r * cos(a);
        var y2 = r * sin(a);
        
        let c = Img.get(x1, y1);
        let b = brightness(c);
        const val = map(b, 0, 255, 1, 10);
        
        push();
        translate(width/2, height/2);
        ellipse(x1, y1, val, val);
        pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates where you're sampling from aren't the same where you're rendering.

Because you use `translate()`, the ellipses themselves are offset based on the centre (but there's nothing changing where you're sampling from in the image (`x1,y1`).

You can offset `x1,y1` to take the centre of the stage into account and then you sample from the right location (and draw offset to the centre):

```js
FG = '#222323';
BG = '#f0f6f0';

function preload() {    
    // Img = loadImage('black.png');
  Img = loadImage('data:image/png;base64,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');
}


function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 500);
    Img.resize(500, 500);
    background(BG);
    fill(FG);
    colorMode(HSB, 255);
    noLoop();
    noStroke(); 
}

function draw() {   
    var r = width;
    var a = 0;
    
    const centerX = width * 0.5;
    const centerY = height * 0.5;
    
    while (r > 1) {
        
        var x1 = centerX + (r * cos(a));
        var y1 = centerX + (r * sin(a));
        
        a += 0.01;
        r -= 0.03;
        
        let c = Img.get(x1, y1);
        let b = brightness(c);
        const val = map(b, 0, 255, 1, 10);
        
      ellipse(x1, y1, val, val);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

(Notice the central area where the source image has a black circle is what based on your mapping. You can reverse that as well if that's more interesting (`const val = map(b, 0, 255, 10, 1);`))